# Как после перезагрузки страницы сохранить класс который был добавлен в html через скрипт

Tags: javascript, html

код js

```
linkItem.on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).next('ul').is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).addClass('harOpen');
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('current');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохранить в [`localstorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) состояние (-я) и, при загрузке страницы, брать состояние (-я) из хранилища.

Answer (score 0):

По моему, использовать сериализацию объекта и последующее восстановление в случае с http и javascript не самое лучшее решение и может привести в дальнейшем к большей путанице.

Возможно что в некоторых случаях можно, или даже лучше избежать перезагрузки всей страницы, конечно если это подходит для задачи.

Как альтернатива, использовать AJAX или WebSocket чтобы не перегружать всю страницу.